# Simplify multiple subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with name loan_emi. I want select last emi payment date, last emi date, total no. of emi, no. of paid emi and no. of unpaid emi. here is my query.

```
SELECT MAX(emi_date)AS pay_date,
  (SELECT MAX(emi_date) FROM loan_emi WHERE l_id=a.l_id AND is_paid=0
  )AS last_date,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM loan_emi WHERE l_id=a.l_id
  )AS tenor,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM loan_emi WHERE l_id=a.l_id AND is_paid=1
  )AS paid,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM loan_emi WHERE l_id=a.l_id AND is_paid=0
  )AS unpaid
FROM loan_emi a
WHERE id   =" + lId + "
AND is_paid=1 GROUP BY l_id
```

But here is multiple sub queries. Please help me to simplify that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you include some minimal sample data please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just put into a single query with a case/when for each field.  This way it is one pass for all the records for the ID in question, no joins, no subqueries.  Also, as I have it, you probably want to PARAMETERIZE your query where indicated for the ID of the account in question...

```
SELECT
      MAX( case when is_paid = 1 then emi_date else null end ) as Pay_Date,
      MAX( case when is_paid = 0 then emi_date else null end ) as Last_Date,
      COUNT(*) as Tenor,
      SUM( case when is_paid = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) as Paid,
      SUM( case when is_paid = 0 then 1 else 0 end ) as Unpaid
   from
      loan_emi
   where
      id = ?ParameterizeYourIncomingID
   group by
      l_id
```

Comment: This may in fact be what the OP wants, but this is not identical to the original query AFAIK.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks. Missed the group by on the "L_ID" column

Comment: Thanks @DRapp ! this is what I want.